# Convert ordinal date (YYYYDDD) to standard date (e.g. UTC = YYYYMMDD )

Tags: mysql, date, date-format, ordinal

I'd like to see the results of a mysql query with a standard date format, `YYYYMMDD` or `MMDDYYYY`.  The table/field has dates in the ordinal date format: `YYYYDDD`.  I tried the DATE_FORMAT function with no success:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(O.otc_eff_date,'%m/%d/%Y') FROM NU.RawCaseOTC O
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(O.otc_eff_date, '%Y%j'),'%m/%d/%Y') FROM NU.RawCaseOTC O
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar  (I can't upvote you because I don't have the required reputation, but I'll be back when I do).